# How to ensure referential integrity in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, foreign-keys

I did some tests in CakePHP and found out, when i manipulate form-data on client side, CakePHP is not automatically ensuring the existence of referenced entities (e.g. option values of select-dropdown).

I found a [validation "exists"](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/farez/2007/05/26/exists-validation-for-evan-s-validation-class), but it's not built-in and seems to be only a workaround.

If I create foreign keys on DB Level, CakePHP's isn't able to handle the exceptions returned by the DB, and following the Convention over Configuration approach, this is not a convenient solution anyway.

So what is the best way, to ensure referential integrity in CakePHP automatically?

Comment: I recommend you to read the offical API and documentation for CakePHP 2.x and not some article that is related to 1.x and seven years old. See http://book.cakephp.org and http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Model.html#_exists

Comment: This is what i did. The Cookbook defines the rules, how to define the links between models, but not how to ensure the integrity of references. "Dependent" is mentioned, but this is only to cascade delets and not for insert/update.

Answer (score 0):

well if you look the article is 2007, think I'd have to run a very old version of cakephp, I guess you would have to look for a more updated article, Now this version 2.x. you would look good with this version items

Answer (score 0):

use `'dependent' => true,`, for that.

```
public $hasMany = array(        
    'UserDevice' => array(
        'className' => 'UserDevice',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )

);
```

Comment: I tried that without effect. In this example CakePHP would not check if the User ID really exists if you add a User Device.

Comment: I think its for Casade Delete only.If thats the case ,you need to write your own code to check if data EXISTS in `users` table manually before inserting into Child table Like `users_devices`